# Is B1/B2 valid US visa will cancelled if I applied for J1 valid US visa?

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas

I already have valid B1/B2 visa (16 AUG 2015 to 12 AUG 2020) and also have valid J1 visa (18 JUL 2017 to 19 MAY 2018)and I used both of it before , so can I visit US using my B1/B2 visa now in JUL 2019 or not it will be cancelled because I already applied for J1?

Comment: You can have both at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can hold both at the same time.

[Example from Quora](https://www.quora.com/Can-we-avail-B1-B2-visa-and-J1-visa-at-the-same-time).

And no, the original [will not be cancelled](https://www.quora.com/Will-the-valid-B-2-visa-be-cancelled-when-you-apply-for-a-J-1).

Worth having a read of both links as there might be some interesting edge cases for you.